# Android activate button on press, not on release

Tags: android, button

Normally in Android, whatever the button is supposed to do gets activated when you press and release the button. Is there a way to change this so that what the button is supposed to do gets activated when you only press it?

Comment: This is generally `mousedown`, but `touchstart` might work for mobile devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an [`OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and check for `ACTION_DOWN`.

Comment: Can I do this through XML? Right now I have

    android:onClick="buttonPressed"

Comment: No, you must set `setOnTouchListener()` in your Java code. (I'm not sure why the `OnClickListener` is the only one that has an equivalent XML attribute.)